# Coordinate shift when converting from Kivy (origin at bottom left) to MatplotLib pyplot (top left)

Tags: python, image

So I`m making an image annotation tool for images to use them with some tensor flow and OpenCV projects. (yes I know there are already made ones, I do it as part of learning experience) To ensure my script is versatile I first make a json file to store my data easily. Already at this stage I store top left of my rectangle with width and height. Then I use another script to convert my json into xml identical to the one seen in this tutorial: [Keras tutorial](https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-train-an-object-detection-model-with-keras/)

The conversion and storage occur in this part of the annotation script:

registration:

```
def on_touch_up(self, touch):
    if abs(self.current_start_point[0] - touch.pos[0]) > 10 and abs(self.current_start_point[1] - touch.pos[1]) > 10:
        x = math.trunc(self.current_start_point[0] if self.current_start_point[0] < touch.pos[0] else touch.pos[0])
        y = math.trunc(self.current_start_point[1] if self.current_start_point[1] > touch.pos[1] else touch.pos[1])
        w = math.trunc(abs(self.current_start_point[0] - touch.pos[0]))
        h = math.trunc(abs(self.current_start_point[1] - touch.pos[1]))
        debug(CLR=GREEN,MSG=f'Registered rectangle with position {x},{y}.\nIts width is {w} and height {h}')

        self.rectangles.append({'x':x,
                                'y':y,
                                'w':w,
                                'h':h})

    self.current_drag = False
    self.current_start_point = False
```

and storage:

```
def do_export(self):
    with open(self.save_file,'r') as fl:
        cur_state = json.loads(fl.read())
        cur_state['root'][self.imname] = self.rectangles
    with open(self.save_file,'w') as fl:
        strung = json.dumps(cur_state,sort_keys=True,indent=4)
        fl.write(strung)

    self.rectangles = []
```

It works fine and displays rectangles accordingly with such function:

```
def update(self,dt):
    self.canvas.clear()

    with self.canvas:
        Rectangle(pos=(0,0),size=(self.tex_w,self.tex_h),texture=self.tex)

        Color(0.9,0,0.2,0.5)
        for rect in self.rectangles:
            Rectangle(pos=(rect['x'],rect['y']-rect['h']),size=(rect['w'],rect['h']))

        if self.current_drag:
            dx = self.current_drag[0] if self.current_drag[0] < self.current_start_point[0] else self.current_start_point[0]
            dy = self.current_drag[1] if self.current_drag[1] < self.current_start_point[1] else self.current_start_point[1]
            dw,dh = abs(self.current_start_point[0]-self.current_drag[0]),abs(self.current_start_point[1]-self.current_drag[1])
            Rectangle(pos=(dx,dy),size=(dw,dh))
```

[image]

Then I convert it into xml as such (only the coordinates part):

```
x_min,y_min,x_max,y_max = item['x'],int(item['y']),item['w'] + item['x'],int(item['y']+item['h'])
        obj = ET.SubElement(root,'object')
        name,pose,truncated,difficult = ET.SubElement(obj,'name'),ET.SubElement(obj,'pose'),ET.SubElement(obj,'truncated'),ET.SubElement(obj,'difficult')
        name.text = 'bob' ; pose.text = 'Unknown' ; truncated.text = str(0) ; difficult.text = str(0)
        bndbox = ET.SubElement(obj,'bndbox')
        min_x,min_y,max_x,max_y = ET.SubElement(bndbox,'xmin'),ET.SubElement(bndbox,'ymin'),ET.SubElement(bndbox,'xmax'),ET.SubElement(bndbox,'ymax')
        min_x.text = str(x_min) ; min_y.text = str(y_min) ; max_x.text = str(x_max) ; max_y.text = str(y_max)
```

Eventually I load it into the dataset class I copied from same tutorial and use matplotlib to show the mask, which shows something like this:
[image]

I clearly see the offset in y but I cant find the origin of it as I clearly pick the top left corner of rectangle in kivy. This is probably something really simple but I just cant find it and I'm stuck on it for couple of days now.

Also JSON for the cat looks like:

```
{
"root": {
    "images\\0.jpg": [
        {
            "h": 101,
            "w": 99,
            "x": 1052,
            "y": 653
        }
    ]
}
```

}

and the XML like:

```
<annotation>
<folder>side</folder>
<filename>0</filename>
<source>Unknown</source>
<size>
    <width>1920</width>
    <height>1080</height>
    <depth>3</depth>
</size>
<segmented>0</segmented>
<object>
    <name>bob</name>
    <pose>Unknown</pose>
    <truncated>0</truncated>
    <difficult>0</difficult>
    <bndbox>
        <xmin>1052</xmin>
        <ymin>653</ymin>
        <xmax>1151</xmax>
        <ymax>754</ymax>
    </bndbox>
</object>
```

Thank you very much in advance, and sorry if it`s something very simple.

Answer (score 1):

My apologies to everyone, I'm retarded. For anyone who has same issue just have `screen height - the y coordinate to convert`, cuz even if u pick different corner the system itself stays.